# File download php 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, download

We are trying to download a mp3 file, we create an iframe in the page and set its source:

```
my_iframe.attr('src',"dl.php?path="+mp3_path+"&name="+mp3_name);
```

mp3 files are set to 777 permission and are accessible, for example:

http://www.gandaldina.org/mp3/Lectures/2013-09-19_Paragraph-30.mp3

dl.php file has this contest:

```
<?php 
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    if(isset($_GET['name'])){
        $name = $_GET['name'];
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$name\"");
    }
    if(isset($_GET['path'])){
       $path = str_replace(' ', '%20', $_GET['path']);
       readfile($path);
    }
    exit;
?>
```

Go to this link and click download icons in the audio player, you will get 403 error in console.

http://gandaldina.org/en/lectures-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%AD%D8%A7%D8%B6%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AA/

Can anybody help solving this error?

Comment: `header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");`

Comment: I have tried to add this line as well in dl.php but I still get the same error when trying to download mp3.

Comment: I did some more testing. It appears download works when I access mp3 file located in same directory as dl.php file, but when I link mp3 file from different directory like this (   http://www.gandaldina.org/mp3/Lectures/2014-09-06_Sincerity01.mp3 )  , I get this error.